# The service is unavailable (OneDrive)

Tags: service, onedrive

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to access a file which is in my OneDrive
through a link to this file. It happens for 2 hours , between 20:00 and 22:00 h Eastern European Time .Has anybody had the same problem and is it continuing to happen during a long period of time(days , months ,years)?

Comment: Is this a question about the OneDrive website, about using the LiveSDK apis to access OneDrive or about using SharePoint Online/OneDrive for Business?  In either case we would need a network trace (I'm a big fan of Fiddler http://getfiddler.com) to understand the nature of the problem.